# Get IIS application pool WMI object for a Non-admin account

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5, get-wmiobject

I wrote a powershell script to stop and start an IIS application pool on a windows server 2008 machine. IIS version is 7.5

I have administrator privileges on the machine and when I run it the script works fine. But when I trigger the same script with a Non-admin Service account it is failing.

The trigger is from CA Release Automation tool, the agent is configured on the machine with the service account. Following is the command where I am stuck.

```
gwmi -Namespace root\webAdministration -class ApplicationPool -Authentication PacketPrivacy | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "siteURL" }
```

Error:

> *****Get-WmiObject : Provider load failure At C:\Users\SVC_DEV_APP\AppData\Local\Temp\tempz_891958570065876740601304.ps1:2
>   char:5 
> + gwmi <<<< -Namespace root\webAdministration -class
>   ApplicationPool 
> + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:)
>   [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException 
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
>   Get-WmiObject : Provider load failure At
>   C:\Users\SVC_DEV_APP\AppData\Local\Temp\tempz_891958570065876740601304.ps1:2
>   char:5 
> + gwmi <<<< -Namespace root\webAdministration -class
>   ApplicationPool + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:)
>   [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException 
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand*****

I have tried getting a WMI object for other windows services(Win32_Service) and it works fine. Only for IIS objects it is throwing the error.

I have given the service account, control(Execute methods, Enable Account, Remote enable) over the namespace(in fact Root and its sub namespaces) as suggested in some forums.

I have also added the service account as IIS Manager, but nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are bumping into UAC. UAC unfortunately impacts WMI.

How to address it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826699(v=vs.85).aspx